# Change default Google Cloud Storage bucket region when creating it in C# application

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am interested in changing Google Cloud Storage bucket region when creating bucket in C# application programmatically. Here is the method:

```
StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create();        
storageClient.CreateBucket(projectId, bucketName);
```

But it seems there is no way to change default region. It should be a very simple thing to do, but I can not find any information on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official Google Cloud Storage sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Storage.cs#L88):

```
    private void CreateRegionalBucket(string location, string bucketName)
    {
        var storage = StorageClient.Create();
        Bucket bucket = new Bucket { Location = location, Name = bucketName };
        storage.CreateBucket(s_projectId, bucket);
        Console.WriteLine($"Created {bucketName}.");
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed that! Thank you!